# virtuemart in custom joomla product article

Tags: javascript, html, joomla, virtuemart, webshop

I have a joomla website on which I want to sell products. The products are on article pages I made myself. But I want to use virtuemart for the payment gateway. But I dont like the look of virtuemart so I want to use the virtuemart code in my own product article but it doesnt add the product to the cart. Can anyone help me out?

```
<div class="vm-product-details-container">
    <div class="spacer-buy-area">
        <!--<div class="ratingbox dummy" title="Not Rated Yet">
        </div>-->
            <div class="product-price" id="productPrice1" style="opacity: 1;">
                <div class="PricebasePriceVariant vm-display vm-price-value">
                    <span class="vm-price-desc">Base price for variant </span>
                    <span class="PricebasePriceVariant">100,00 €</span>
                </div>
                <span class="price-crossed"></span>
                <div class="PricesalesPrice vm-display vm-price-value">
                    <span class="vm-price-desc">Sales price </span>
                    <span class="PricesalesPrice">100,00 €</span>
                </div>
                <div class="PricepriceWithoutTax vm-display vm-price-value">
                    <span class="vm-price-desc">Sales price without tax </span>
                    <span class="PricepriceWithoutTax">100,00 €</span>
                </div>
                <div class="PricediscountAmount vm-nodisplay" style="display: none;">0</div>
                <div class="PricetaxAmount vm-nodisplay" style="display: none;">0</div>
                <div class="PriceunitPrice vm-nodisplay" style="display: none;">0</div>
            </div>

         <div class="clear">
         </div>
         <div class="addtocart-area">
                <form method="post" class="product js-recalculate" action="#">
                    <div class="vm-customfields-wrap">
                    </div>          

                    <div class="addtocart-bar">
                                                <!-- <label for="quantity1" class="quantity_box">Quantity: </label> -->
                            <span class="quantity-box">
                                <input type="text" class="quantity-input js-recalculate" name="quantity[]" 
                                 value="1" init="1" step="1">
                            </span>
                            <span class="quantity-controls js-recalculate">
                                <input type="button" class="quantity-controls quantity-plus">
                                <input type="button" class="quantity-controls quantity-minus">
                            </span>
                            <span class="addtocart-button">
                                <input type="submit" name="addtocart" class="addtocart-button" value="Add to Cart" title="Add to Cart">
                            </span>             
                            <input type="hidden" name="virtuemart_product_id[]" value="1">
                            <noscript>
                                <input type="hidden" name="task" value="add"/>
                            </noscript> 
                    </div>          
                    <input type="hidden" name="option" value="com_virtuemart">
                    <input type="hidden" name="view" value="cart">
                    <input type="hidden" name="virtuemart_product_id[]" value="1">
                    <input type="hidden" name="pname" value="VinTec n01">
                    <input type="hidden" name="pid" value="1">
                    <input type="hidden" name="Itemid" value="524">     
                </form>

        </div>



    </div>
</div>
```